# Passing a 2D array to HTML using googlescript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to pass a 2D array created in a Javascript file here:

Code.gs

```
function getPermits()
{
  Logger.log('Starting permits');
  var permits =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('Got permits: ' + permits [0][0]);

  return permits;
}
```

And I call that function with a handler in this html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function onSuccess(numUnread) {
    alert('You have ' + numUnread[0][0]
       + ' unread messages in your Gmail inbox.');
      document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = numUnread[0][0];


}

   function onFail(numUnread){
   alert('Script failed!');
   }

 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getPermits();
 google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFail).getPermits();
</script>
```

The `Logger.log('Got permits: ' + permits[0][0]);`
call works perfect no matter what. However, while I can pass a 1D array in this manner and it works fine, passing a 2D array is causing this to fail. Why does this happen? Am I using improper syntax for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringify it as a JSON object, then you can pass just a String, which works fine:

```
return JSON.stringify(permits);
```

And on HTML:

```
function onSuccess(numUnread) {
  numUnread = JSON.parse(numUnread);
```

Comment: is this technically necessary? As in, is there no alternative? If so, why does using a 1d array work just fine but this doesn't?

Comment: What's the data in the permits? Number, string, dates...?

Comment: The data is coming from a google spreadsheet that contains numbers, dates, and strings

Comment: AFAIK, Dates are not a permitted type to pass trough Apps Script Servers and the Javascript Client. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run, you can try to encode the date or stringfiy it.

Comment: Ahh thanks very much! I have confirmed that without the dates I can return the 2d array successfully. Is JSON the goto method then for handling dates?

Comment: For my cases it has been the best case, you can also pass it as a string in the Array.